# bash shell loop through directory listing contents and executability

Tags: shell-script, ls, wc

I'm currently working on a homework assignment and I need to take a given directory path and from that list the files and directories in it. While also including if it's executable or not. I'm also restricted by not being allowed to use any other languages except bash.

My original thought was to use `ll` and `cut` to get what I needed but I couldn't seem to get it to work. Then I was thinking I could use something like (not working, just an idea)

```
read input
for f in $input
do
if [[ -x "$f" ]]
then
echo "$f is executable"
else
echo "$f is not executable"
fi
done
```

I need the output to be something like and I'm not sure how to get there

> file-name1 is executable
>
> file-name2 is not executable
>
> directory1 is executable

Comment: can you tell how this code is failing ? `[[ -x filename ]]` is a perfectly legitimate construct in bash. Would you be using some other shell may be ?

Comment: Rather than `for f in $input`, try `for f in ${input}/*`.  Making sure the value of `$input` is a readable directory is an exercise I shall leave for you.

Comment: why are you looping over $input? On the assumption that the user is entering "a (single) directory path"...

Comment: As I see it, the OP's intent is to loop over the _contents_ of the directory specified as the input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like

```
my=($(ls -la $dr |awk {'print $9'}))  
echo ${my[@]}  
for i in "${my[@]}"  
do  
    if [[ -x "$i" ]]  
    then  
        echo "File '$i' is executable"  
    else  
        echo "File '$i' is not executable or found"  
    fi  
done
```

Comment: $dr you can replace with your directory.

Comment: Don't parse the output of `ls`.

Comment: tmp]$ ./test.sh
. .. 1 2 3 4 5 a b c d e
File '.' is executable
File '..' is executable
File '1' is not executable or found
File '2' is not executable or found
File '3' is not executable or found
File '4' is not executable or found
File '5' is not executable or found
File 'a' is not executable or found
File 'b' is not executable or found
File 'c' is not executable or found
File 'd' is not executable or found
File 'e' is not executable or found

Comment: No, seriously, don't parse `ls`.  http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Answer (score 0):

You're taking a directory and then checking to see whether the directory itself is executable, and not looking into its contents as you want to.

```
read input
for f in ${input}/*; do
    echo -n "$f is "
    type=""
    if [[ -x "$f" ]]; then
        type="executable"
    else
        type="non-executable"
    fi
    if [[ -d "$f" ]]; then
        type="$type directory"
    fi
    echo "$type"
done
```

Making sure the value of `$input` is a readable directory is an exercise I shall leave for you.